# Ubuntu 14.04 mysql-client-5.7 dependencies issue on update: Permanent solution?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, mysql

When I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` my package system gets broken because of mysql packages.

I have tried to unistall the client and all the other packages, then to install it again but the issue came up on the next update.

So far the only working solution I have found is the following:

```
mabe@ubuntu:~ $ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for mabe: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.6
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-client-5.6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,564 kB of archives.
After this operation, 151 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 452900 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.6_5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.6_5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql_config_editor', which is also in package libmysqlclient-dev 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.6_5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mabe@ubuntu:~ $ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.6_5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 452900 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.6_5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql_config_editor', which is also in package libmysqlclient-dev 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config_editor.1.gz', which is also in package libmysqlclient-dev 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client-5.6:
 mysql-client-5.6 depends on mysql-client-core-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-client-core-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-5.6 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-client-5.6
mabe@ubuntu:~ $ sudo apt-get -f 
installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tzdata (2016d-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Rome'
Local time is now:      Tue Apr 26 09:43:03 CEST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Apr 26 07:43:03 UTC 2016.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Setting up libapt-inst1.5:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.13) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (50.0.2661.86-1) ...
Setting up libpcrecpp0:amd64 (1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libsnmp-base (5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libsnmp30:amd64 (5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
mysql start/running, process 11619
Setting up tzdata-java (2016d-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
```

There is an better and permanent solution than `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.6_5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb` after every update?

Thank you in advance for your help

**Output of `apt-cache policy mysql-common libmysqlclient-dev`**

```
mabe@ubuntu:~/Development/lumen-etl (development)$ apt-cache policy mysql-common libmysqlclient-dev
mysql-common:
  Installed: 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
  Candidate: 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
  Version table:
 *** 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libmysqlclient-dev:
  Installed: 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
  Candidate: 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04
  Version table:
 *** 5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: It seems you currently have two versions of MySQL (5.6 and 5.7). You must choose one.

Comment: according to `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql` I only have installed 5.6 version. (mysql, libdbd-mysql-perl, libmysqlclient-dev,
libmysqlclient18:amd64, libmysqlclient20:amd64,
mysql-apt-config, mysql-client-5.6,
mysql-client-core-5.6, mysql-common,
mysql-common-5.6, mysql-server-5.6, mysql-server-core-5.6       
mysql-workbench-community)

Comment: Try `dpkg -l | grep mysql`, it will also display version numbers.

Comment: actually `libmysqlclient-dev`  and  'mysql-common` are on 5.7 version. Would you revert to the 5.6 (somehow) or it might be better to unistall everything and reinstall? there is a command to clean up my repository from all the different mysql version?

Comment: `mysql-common` and `libmysqlclient-dev`on 14.04 should be on 5.5, unless you have additional repositories. Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-common libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: @fkraiem should I remove `http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages` from my package list?

Comment: Right, so you have two repositories which provide MySQL: the official Ubuntu 14.04 repositories provide 5.5, and the official MySQL ones provide 5.7. It seems you want to install 5.6; do you really need 5.6? It would be much easier to go with 5.5 or 5.7 since you have repositories for them.

Comment: Actually I simply added the repository from [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) .  I would rather go for the 5.7 if it is supported by Ubuntu 14.04. Should I remove all the packages before to install again? Could you write an answer with some suggestions? You were very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two repositories which provide MySQL: the official Ubuntu 14.04 ones provide MySQL 5.5, and the [official MySQL ones](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) provide 5.7. This is why you cannot manually install 5.6 packages without some forcing, it would be better to go with either 5.5 or 5.7. In that case you should:

1. Uninstall all residual 5.6 packages, you can find them with `dpkg -l | grep mysql`.
2. *If you want to go with 5.5,* remove the MySQL repositories from your `sources.list`, and also uninstall all 5.7 packages.
3. Finally, install `mysql-client-5.5` or `mysql-client-5.7`, depending on which one you want.

Comment: If I want to go with 5.7 what should I uninstall? Thank you

Comment: Just the 5.6 packages, you don't need to uninstall the 5.7 ones since if you do they're going to be installed again anyway when you install `mysql-client-5.7`.